# Add next row dynamically after third column

Tags: android

this is desired table layout:

```
+++++++++++++
+   +   +   +
+ 1 + 2 + 3 +
+   +   +   +
+++++++++++++
+   +   +   +
+ 4 + 5 + 6 +
+   +   +   +
+++++++++++++
+   +   +   +
+ 7 + 8 + - +
+   +   +   +
+++++++++++++
```

My table is dynamically created based on json data:

```
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray( all_gpio_json );

    for ( i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

    ...some dynamic table generation code like this:
    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
    Switch sw = new Switch( this );
    row.addView(sw);

}
tl.addView( row );
```

There is no problem to have table generated so, that each json value is represented by unique row, however i'd like to have layout that will have maximum 3 columns per row, and number of rows will be dynamically growing as long as there are json data in the loop.

I tried to add new row after existing row has 3 items filled already:

```
if (i % 3 == 1) {TableRow new_row = new TableRow( this );}
```

But im getting an error when new_row is supposed to be added:

```
  E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.comain.tests, PID: 15519
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.comainxxx.tests/com.comainxxx.tests.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Anyone would have an idea how to achieve this to add new row on the fly?

EDIT: Solved by implementing grid view, that is more suitable for this task.

Comment: what is mean exactly about this sentence of u ??? (But this is not possible in java i guess)

Comment: i updated my question adding the error code

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in java. U need to declare that variable outside the if condition. Try below code

```
 TableRow new_row = new TableRow(this);

  for ( i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

     if (i % 3 == 0 && i != 0) {new_row = new TableRow( this );}
     .......
     Switch sw = new Switch( this );
     new_row .addView(sw);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Solved by implementing grid view, that is more suitable for this task.